How to use xbindkeys & xdotool to bind mouse button?
How can i use right mouse key to paste at default terminal application ?
i added to my ~/.xbindkeysrc
"xdotool click 3"
    b:3

But it makes right mouse key to stop showing menu but paste doesn't work...

Not sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve, but it looks to me that you try to convert button 3 to button 3...?

Note also that these tools will not work on Wayland.

@egmont how to make right mouse key to paste at default terminal application ?

@vanadium i am using X11

@emoxam Unfortunately I don't know, I would have answered your question then. It definitely doesn't have this option built-in, and I'm not very familiar with xbindkeys/xdotool and friends. But definitely not by mapping button 3 into button 3. Did you mean to map button 3 to button 2, perhaps?

It will be good to add that explicitly to your question: Ubuntu currently defaults to Wayland. It will also be good to rephrase your question more generally: now you insist on a solution using xbindkeys and xdotool. Perhaps, that is not the solution. And now, you bind button 3 to button 3...

Seems like that's the working way to gnome terminal and asbru connection manager
killall xbindkeys && echo -e '"xdotool key ctrl+shift+v"\nb:3' >> ~/.xbindkeysrc && xbindkeys
